# Do I have to add dependency lib into makefile to generate shared library in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to create a shared library libX.so, but the libX.so contain one cpp which dependens on libY.a or libY.so.

So, Do I have to add -I -l related for libY to create libX.so when linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you want to resolve external symbols from dynamic libraries you need to say when linking your library something like `-L/path/to/libY -llibY`. Also, unless you are a big fan of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you may want to say `-wl,-rpath=/path/to/libY` and Goodle the subject of `RUNPATH` vs `RPATH`.

Comment: I know it, I mean that if I doesn't add -Land -l, if the linking will failed when creating libx.so

Comment: It depends. If you are building in GCC with something like `-Wl,-znow -Wl,-zdefs -Wl,--fatal-warnings` then build will fail unless you link all required libraries (and this is the recommended way). Else it will most probably pass and you will see the problem for the first time when you try running a binary linked with your library.

Comment: do you mean the link mayn't fail if I not using -W1 in gcc?

Comment: If you do not tell linker to strictly check all unresolved symbols while linking your shared library, it will assemble your library and not complain of any unresolved symbols. I don't know what `-W1` option is.

Comment: so in brief, I know how to disable complain unresolved symbols when linking to create libx.so? Many thanks to you!

Comment: I write one test program, it seems it will report undefined reference be default if I not add -I -l liby.so into libx.so's makefile.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you are using symbols from `libY.so`, there's a big change the whoever links with your `libX.so` will have to link against `libY.so` also.

But, if libY is a static library, i.e: `libY.a` you have two options

Option 1:

As with a `.so`, you can just link with `libY.a` and users will probably have to link against `libY.a`.

Option 2:

Use `libY.a` as just another object file, the linker will unpack `libY.so` and do the linking for you.
 Using this method nobody has to know you are using `libY.a`.

```
g++ $(OBJS) /path/to/libY.a -o libX.so
```